# Proving an inequality regarding the tenth moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Let $Y$ be a random variable with $\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X) = X$, where $X \sim \mathrm{U}[0,1]$. Prove that $\mathbb{E}(Y^{10}) \geq \frac{1}{11}$.

I tried using Jensen's inequality and found out that $\mathbb{E}(Y^{10}) \geq \frac{1}{2^{10}}$, but it's too rough. Would thank you for any suggestions.

---

Based on suggestions from comments, I reproduce my Jensen's-inequality argument below:

$X\sim\mathrm{U}[0,1]$ is a r.v. uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. By the law of total expectation, $$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X))=\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{2}$$ $h(x)=x^{10}$ is convex, so by Jensen's inequality, $\mathbb{E}(h(X))\geq h(\mathbb{E}(X))$, that is $$\mathbb{E}(Y^{10})≥(\mathbb{E}(Y))^{10}=\frac{1}{210}$$

Comment: Hard to say where the error was since you don't show us what you did. (Seems to me a suitable version of Jensen's inequality gives $1/11$ immediately...)

Comment: I have a conjecture where the $1/2^{10}$ could have come from. What's the definition of $U[0,1]$?

Comment: $X \sim \mathrm{U}[0,1]$ is a r.v. uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. I did the following: By the law of total expectation, $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Y \mid X)) = \mathbb{E}(X) = 1/2$. $h(x) = x^{10}$ is convex, so by Jensen's inequality, $\mathbb{E}(h(X)) \geq h(\mathbb{E}(X))$, that is $\mathbb{E}(Y^{10}) \geq (\mathbb{E}(Y))^{10} = 1/2^{10}$.

Comment: OK but note $\mathbb{E}(X^{10}) = \int\limits_0^1 x^{10}\, dx = \frac{1}{11}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First:
$$E[X^{10}]=\int_{(0,\infty)}P(X^{10}\geq t)dt=\int_{(0,1)}P(X\geq t^{1/10})dt=\int_{(0,1)}(1-t^{1/10})dt=1-\frac{10}{11}=\frac{1}{11}$$
Then by using Jensen's of conditional expectations:
$$E[Y^{10}]=E[E[Y^{10}|X]]\geq E[E[Y|X]^{10}]=E[X^{10}]=\frac{1}{11}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think about Jensen's inequality for CONDITIONAL expectations.